# Run Asp Core MVC on Docker - the static files / wwwroot files are not loading

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, dockerfile

When I start my container, the page starts without styles, scripts, images and other static files - calls to load them return 404.

I would like to say that when I access the app folder, the wwwroot folder exists.

I  tested it in my Release folder (with dotnet command). But in Docker it does not work. Yes, I'm using `UseStaticFiles` in my Startup class.

My Dockerfile is simple, it just runs the app. But I previously built and published the app, and the wwwroot is there.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

COPY bin/Release app/

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "app/MyApp.SGC.Site.dll"]
```

[image: wwwroot exists]

The application runs, but there are many erros:

[image: Errors]

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must run the `dotnet publish` command so that all the required files are copied into your app folder.

Your release folder only has the dll files for your application so when you copy it into the docker container the `wwwroot` files are not copied.

If you create a new web app project and tick the Docker support option it will make a dockerfile for you. Create a sample project so you can see the recommended way to containerize your application.

Here is an example that uses the publish command:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["MyApp.SGC.Site/MyApp.SGC.Site.csproj", "MyApp.SGC.Site/"]
RUN dotnet restore "MyApp.SGC.Site/MyApp.SGC.Site.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/MyApp.SGC.Site"
RUN dotnet build "MyApp.SGC.Site.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
# publish will copy wwwroot files as well
RUN dotnet publish "MyApp.SGC.Site.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish
WORKDIR /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyApp.SGC.Site.dll"]
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for the answer, but my release folder has the wwwroot. And the wwwroot in the container bash is there.

Comment: I tried using this command default from dockerfile, but it gives me an error.

Comment: I created a simple project "TestandoDocker" with docker support. it gives me error at Step 5/17 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
 ---> cc3d07a86ecd
Step 6/17 : WORKDIR /src
 ---> Running in 4f1b3f2d59c7
Removing intermediate container 4f1b3f2d59c7
 ---> 42df2e9d8cdd
Step 7/17 : COPY ["TestandoDocker/TestandoDocker.csproj", "TestandoDocker/"]
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder961121729/TestandoDocker/TestandoDocker.csproj: no such file or directory

Comment: You can try in Visual Studio to right-click the Dockerfile and choose "Build Docker image"

Comment: Interesting. Why docker build -t testandodocker .  ((inside the same folder of my dockerfile) ) fails on STEP  7 (ABOVE) AND docker build -f .  "c:\users\MYUSER\source\repos\testandodocker\testandodocker\dockerfile" --force-rm -t testandodocker  --label "com.microsoft.created-by=visual-studio" --label "com.microsoft.visual-studio.project-name=TestandoDocker" work?

Comment: @dockerfails Did you solve it ?? I am having the same issue ;(, Plz let me know if u did

Comment: Same issue here, wwwroot folder/files exist in the docker container, I can `docker exec ls` and see them, but they won't load when I load my site.

Comment: same problem. just doesn't work, files all present.

Answer (score 0):

For someone using Docker and you are sure that the Container contains your static files but still getting 404.

Check your Dockerfile if you have WORKDIR directive:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
WORKDIR /app # this line
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5000
COPY --from=build /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "YourApp.dll"]
```

Then in Program.cs (or Startup.cs) make sure the root path starts with "/app":

```
builder.Services.AddSpaStaticFiles(config => config.RootPath = "/app/wwwroot");
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just add the code below to your ASP.NET Core WebAPI Project File .csproj**. It will copy your folder and all your files into your *Docker image* or *Publish* folder, depending on which process you are trying to run. Be sure to change the folder name to your own...

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="MySubFolder\*">
        <CopyToPublishDirectory>always</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```